# i3 - a hateful handful of font sizes for my desktop

Tags: fonts, gui, i3, gtk, qt

Since I installed i3 on Arch Linux I noticed a too big font size (in what was the first thing I saw, the i3bar at the bottom), so I changed the font size in the `.config/i3/config` file (now the line reads `font pango:DejaVuSansMono Nerd Font Mono 5`.

Soon enough I noticed that the size of the menu bars of the application was too big, so I edited it with Lxappearance (now the default font is `DejaVuSansMono Nerd Font Book` with size `4`) and the GUI of Lxappearance itself looks perfect.

But the rest still does not, as you can see from the screenshot: the font is too big, I'd say huge, in the floating `Open` window, wherease it is tiny, if not invisible, in the `Audacity` window on the right; finally it seems normal on the `TikZiT` window on the left.

In addition (I don't know how to take a picture of this, but I'm sure it wouldn't add anything to this question), if I right-click on the Dropbox icon I see a huge font in the white pop-up menu (the same font I see by hovering with the cursor on that icon); when I do the same with Skype (not in the picture) the font i see is the tiny one on the Arc-dark pop-up menu.

I'm new to this do-all-by-yourself-from-scratch world in which ArchLinux and i3 live. And I'd rather not give up after a week or two.

[image]

**EDIT 1**

Here another picture where `B` are the fonts looking quite ok (I say quite, since I don't even know where they come from), whereas `A` are the too-tiny fonts. Which are not set by `qt5ct`.

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I start thinking that maybe is not a conflict between GTK and Qt: as you can see in the following screenshot, I've set similar but definitely not identical themes with `qt5ct` (left) and `lxappearance` (right), but `pavucontrol` (center), which uses GTK, present that tiny unreadable font.

[image]

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Comment: you may need to set environment variables in X startup files to enforce a default theme on toolkits like GTK or Qt.  `GTK_THEME` may be sufficient.

Comment: @quixotic, could you please give more details about what to do? I'm reading [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications) page, and [this section](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Qt#Configuration_of_Qt5_apps_under_environments_other_than_KDE_Plasma), but I'm not sure I've understood what to do. Sure, I've some idea about what I could try, but, given I'm so newbie, _guess&try_ is a good chance to break everything down.

Comment: I've followed [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Qt#Configuration_of_Qt5_apps_under_environments_other_than_KDE_Plasma) (which was suggested [here too](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=213445) and tried installing `qt5ct` and putting `[ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" = "KDE" ] || [ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" = "GNOME" ] || export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME="qt5ct"` in `~/.xprofile`,  so now I have another GUI application to set font sizes and stuff, but tiny fonts are still nearly microscopic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem myself by pure chance, while trying to make `steam` work. While troubleshooting, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/903488/523488) led me to realize that `nvidia` drivers were installed along side `xf86-video-nouveau` and `mesa`, so I run `sudo pacman -R nvidia` and reboot, hoping that `steam` would then work, but I "happly" found that extremely tiny font everywhere, so I just had to change fonts in `i3` config file, `.Xdefaults`, qutebrowser setting, ... since all I had set at the time I posted this question, was conditioned by the conflicting drivers.