# Why do some fonts appear zoomed in after system update?

Tags: x11, fonts, dwm, dmenu

Since the last system update, for various applications the font size has increased. Even one application for which I can be sure, that it has not been replaced, because I have a custom version and install it from source (see [dmenu](https://tools.suckless.org/dmenu/)).

[image: Increased DMenu-Font]

As you can see in the picture, the font for dmenu appears ridiculously large. The screenshot also shows which font was specified in the source code and the output of fc-list, which indicates, that the font is installed.

Some other applications (such as gimp) show a similar phenomenon.

[image: Gimp ridiculous font size]

The overall resolution is full hd 1920x1080.

What happened and how can I reverse it? It is surprising to me, that some applications such as the terminal (alacritty) or VS Code still render fine. I already checked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449876/i3-a-hateful-handful-of-font-sizes-for-my-desktop) and made sure that no nvidia drivers are installed (ie. `sudo pacman -Q | grep nvidia` shows no output)

Comment: Try searching Google for arcolinux's YouTube channel.
Eric has a few recent videos about this.

Comment: What you describe may be [this issue](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/issues/1241#note_1153655), introduced in xserver 21.1 by a change that, according to the comment the link points to, is apparently going to be reverted (found via [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2002487#p2002487) on bbs.archlinux.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I installed the `xorg-xrdb` package which provides X11 access to the file [.Xresources](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/x_resources) .

```
sudo pacman -S xorg-xrdb
```

Then I created `.Xresources` inside my home directory with the following content

```
*.dpi: 96
```

Lastly I have to make sure that `.Xresources` is loaded, so I added the following line to my `.xinitrc`

```
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```